# Not able to refer a method using composition in java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, composition

Why is this allowed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BurgerClass {

    private DefaultMenuClass defaultMenu;
    ArrayList<String> burgerMenuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public void displayBurgerMenu() {
        
        burgerMenuItems = defaultMenu.getDefaultBurgerMenu();
        for (String burger : burgerMenuItems) {
            System.out.println(burger + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

And this isn't:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BurgerClass {

    private DefaultMenuClass defaultMenu;
    ArrayList<String> burgerMenuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    burgerMenuItems = defaultMenu.getDefaultBurgerMenu(); //error here
    public void displayBurgerMenu() {
        
        
        for (String burger : burgerMenuItems) {
            System.out.println(burger + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `defaultMenu` is never initialized

Comment: Even when initialized, a method couldn't be called outside a method.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the specific question, the reason why the first is "allowed" and the second isn't ——

Neither one is "allowed" or "disallowed"

In both cases, as Mureinik says, `defaultMenu` is never initialized. In the first case it doesn't matter, because `displayBurgerMenu()` is never called, so you never reach the line `burgerMenuItems = defaultMenu.getDefaultBurgerMenu();` which *would* cause an error.

In the second case you *do* attempt to call it, at the line you've marked `//error here` so you get (I assume<sup>*</sup>) a NullPointerException.

Either way, you need to initialize `defaultMenu` to be something that is non-null before you attempt to call a method on it.

You need to do something along the lines of
`private DefaultMenuClass defaultMenu = new DefaultMenuClass(<some-params?>);`

or have some other way to get a `DefaultMenuClass` object. It's impossible to tell how that should happen given only the code you've presented in the question.

---

Separately, and not having anything to do with your error, it's pointless to do both
`ArrayList<String> burgerMenuItems = new ArrayList<String>();`
and then
`burgerMenuItems = defaultMenu.getDefaultBurgerMenu();`

You initialize `burgerMenuItems` to an empty `ArrayList` then you immediately throw that list away by setting burgerMenuItems to the list returned by `.getDefaultBurgerMenu()` (if there had been no error and something was returned)

---

* You really should *say* what error you are getting in your question, and not leave us to assume something.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Data
@Builder
class BurgerClass {
    private DefaultMenuClass defaultMenu;

    public void displayBurgerMenu() {
        List<String> burgerMenuItems = defaultMenu.getDefaultBurgerMenu();
        for (String burger : burgerMenuItems) {
            System.out.println(burger + "\n");
        }
    }
}

@Data
@Builder
class DefaultMenuClass {
    List<String> defaultBurgerMenu;

    public DefaultMenuClass(List<String> defaultBurgerMenu) {
        this.defaultBurgerMenu = defaultBurgerMenu;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BurgerClass obj = BurgerClass.builder().defaultMenu(DefaultMenuClass.builder().defaultBurgerMenu(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Item1", "Item2"})).build()).build();
        obj.displayBurgerMenu();
    }
}
```

As you can able to see in above code,i am initialize all attribute of BurgerClass by providing builder pattern.

Also you can initialize dafaultMenu attributes using constructor. And while creating an instance of **`BurgerClass`** pass value of **`DefaultMenuClass`**.

```
 public BurgerClass(DefaultMenuClass defaultMenu) {
        this.defaultMenu = defaultMenu;
    }
```

Just run above code, you will get an idea.